# Not able to close a HTML dialog via Selenium Webdriver using Java

Tags: java, jquery, selenium

Below is my HTML code and I am trying to close the dialog using selenium webdriver.

```
    <div class="ui-dialog dialog ">
    <div class="od-ui-dialog-content dialog_content">
    <div class="od-ui-dialog-box ui_dialog_box">
    <div class="od-ui-dialog-image-abc”></div> 
    <div class="od-ui-dialog-box-header dialog_box_header"></div>
    <div class="dialog_close_abc od-ui-dialog-abc”>
    <span class="od-ui-dialog-close-abc”>r</span> 
    <div  class="od-ui-dialog-box-content "></div> 
     <div  class="od-ui-dialog-box-footer dialog_footer">
    </div>  </div> </div>
```

I have tried this code, but it didn't get work for me.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("od-ui-dialog-close-abc"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

But its not working

---

Comment: Can you add what Java code you tried for closing the dialog ? Also if you can add some more surrounding HTML to see details of dialog.

Comment: One of the reasons of which the span is not visible while interacting is because you probably need to wait some event, before selecting the span, so that it could be visible, clickable, etc

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you are selecting the span it is not yet visible.
You should wait until it is visible. You can do something like this. (In C# but you will easy convert it to java)

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
                .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName("od-ui-dialog-close-abc")));
element.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As per the HTML you provided you can use the following line of code to close the dialog box:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='od-ui-dialog-close-abc' and text()='r']")).click();
```

Incase you are facing an `ElementNotVisible` exception you can induce `ExplicitWait` to wait for the element to be clickable as follows:

```
WebDriverWait wait8 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element8 = wait8.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='od-ui-dialog-close-abc' and text()='r']")));
element8.click();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.